# assembly 2 programs change each other

Tags: assembly, nasm, fasm

I wonder why when you execute 2 assembly program at the same time or they use threads so it will look like this.

```
//program1
mov eax,1
add eax,50

program 2
xor eax,eax
add eax,eax
```

Registers unlike ram can be accessed through any program so how does these programs doesn't
change each other?
I mean that program 1 instruction 1 can be after instruction 1 command 2 
Help!

Comment: Read about [context switching](http://wiki.osdev.org/Context_Switching).

Answer (score 2):

The operating system makes sure different programs don't mess with each other's registers. Otherwise, any kind of multitasking would be impossible.

All programs (even ones not written in assembly in the first place) constantly change registers. That's just how the CPU works; there's no way around it. Since the task switch may happen any moment - between any two assembly instructions - the OS makes sure that when the a program gets control back, the former values of registers are restored. Registers are like variables - how'd you feel if the variables in your program changed their values unpredictably at random moments?

Internally, when an OS creates a thread, it also allocates a memory chunk, large enough to hold all registers in the CPU. When a task switch happens and the thread loses control, the OS saves all the registers there. When a thread regains control, the registers are restored.

Different programs (processes) run as different threads, as far as the OS kernel is concerned. Each process has at least one thread - the main one. Even if you run the same program twice, you'll end up with two different processes and two threads, one per process, and they won't see or change each other's registers.

For sharing information between threads in the same process, you may use memory. For sharing information between processes, you can use shared memory or other interprocess communication methods. All those are provided by the OS; the CPU itself has rather little provisions for multitasking.

Answer (score 1):

With multicore cpus each core has its own set of registers. For multitasking with only one core all register will be saved before switching to another task or thread.

Dirk